# Autocompletar "input" después de seleccionar campo "select" usando select2 de jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-8

Tengo un formulario en el cual realizo una búsqueda de "ordenes de servicio" con "select2" de query

```
<select 
     class="form-control col-md-6" name="osSearch" id="osSearch">
</select>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var self = this;
        $('#osSearch').select2({
            width: '100%',
            placeholder: 'Buscar',
            ajax: {
                url: '/autocomplete-search-orden',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                text: item.folioSerie,
                                id: item.id,
                                cliente: item.RFC,
                                producto: item.descripcionProd
                            }
                        })
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        });

    </script>
```

Necesito que al seleccionar la "orden de servicio" se autocomplete el campo "cliente" en mi formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando encontré que se podía hacer usando " on ('change') ",
sin embargo no logro obtener el cliente, esta es mi funcion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(#osSearch).on('change', function(){
                var osID = $(this).val();
                        $.each(clientes, function (index, value){
                            $('#cliente_id').value("index");
                        })
                    });
                
            });
    </script>
```

> El controlador

```
public function getCliente(Request $request){

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $clientes = cliente::where('osID', $request->osID)->get();
        }
            return response()->json();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo (*y con temor a equivocarme*) que al construir los `options` del `select` pasas el `idCliente` al atributo `cliente` tal que `cliente: item.RFC`, podrías obtener este dato de la siguiente forma:

```js
//Detectar el evento change del select
$('#osSearch').on('change', function() {
  //obtener el valor del atributo 'cliente' del option seleccionado
  let idCliente = $('#osSearch option:selected').attr('cliente');
  //Pasar el valor obtenido al input cliente_id
  $('#cliente_id').val(idCliente);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control col-md-6" name="osSearch" id="osSearch">
  <option value="" hidden>seleccione</option>
  <option id="1" cliente="2221" producto="descripcion1">AE1001</option>
  <option id="2" cliente="2222" producto="descripcion2">AE1002</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="cliente_id">
```

Cabe resaltar que:

1. Debes envolver entre comillas simples o dobles el selector del elemento sobre el que necesites operar, en este caso `$('#osSearch')...`
2. Para asignar un valor a cualquier elemento usando `jQuery` solo debes usar `.val()` así: `$('#cliente_id').val(idCliente);`

Ajusta el ejemplo a tu código y si surgen dudas, deja un comentario.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, me sirvio tu respuesta para aplicar la logica a mi proyecto, tambien me di cuenta que tal como lo planteas estaba intentando enviar en el option mas de un valor, cuando solo debe recibir el id y texto, abajo pondre como lo resolvi

Comment: Puedes pasar tantos valores como sean necesarios utilizando atributos personalizados o aún mejor, utilizando el atributo estándar `data-option`. Sólo es necesario reemplazar la segunda parte con lo que necesites. Por ejemplo: `data-cliente` o `data-producto`. Y luego, en `jQuery` lo puedes capturar de la siguiente manera: `let idCliente = $('#osSearch option:selected').data('cliente');`

Answer (score 0):

Muestro como lo resolví por si alguien esta en la misma situación, utilizo laravel 8 y select2 de jquery, al igual al final añadiré el link del video con el cual me guie

Aquí están mis tablas de base de datos para que se orienten más:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quería hacer era un campo select autocomplete con el cual iba a buscar una orden de servicio, al seleccionarla se tenían que autocompletar los campos cliente y producto que estuvieran relacionados con esa orden.

Asi quedo el codigo:

> Función que obtiene ordenes de servicio con select2

```js
$('#os_id').select2({
  width: '100%',
  placeholder: 'Buscar',
  ajax: {
    url: '/autocomplete-search-orden',
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            text: item.folioSerie,
            id: item.id
          }

        })
      };
    },
    cache: true,
  }

});
```

> Función para obtener al cliente y producto

```js
< script >
  $('#os_id').on('change', function() {
    var idOS = $(this).val();
    if ($.trim(idOS) != '') {
      $.get('/clientesSearch', {
        idOS: idOS
      }, function(clientes) {
        $('#cliente_id').empty();
        $.each(clientes, function(index, value) {
          $('#cliente_id').append("<option value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</option>");
        })
      });
    }

  }); <
/script>

<
script >
  $('#os_id').on('change', function() {
    var idOrden = $(this).val();
    if ($.trim(idOrden) != '') {
      $.get('/productosSearch', {
        idOrden: idOrden
      }, function(productos) {
        $('#producto_id').empty();
        $.each(productos, function(index, value) {
          $('#producto_id').append("<option value='" + index + "'>" + value + "</option>");
        })
      });
    }

  }); <
/script>
```

> Función para obtener folios de ordenes de servicio

```js
public
function selectSearchOS(Request $request) {
  $orden = [];

  if ($request - > has('q')) {
    $buscarO = $request - > q;
    $orden = inventario::join('producto', 'producto.id', '=', 'inventario.producto_id') -
      > join('os', 'os.id', '=', 'inventario.OS_id') -
      > join('cliente', 'cliente.id', '=', 'os.cliente_id') -
      > select('os.id', 'os.folioSerie', 'producto.descripcionProd', 'cliente.RFC') -
      > where('folioSerie', 'LIKE', "%$buscarO%") -
      > get();
  }
  return response() - > json($orden);
}
```

> Rutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Controlador

```
public function getProducto(Request $request)
 {
   
    if($request->ajax()){

        $productos = inventario::join('producto','producto.id','=','inventario.producto_id')
        ->join('os','os.id','=', 'inventario.OS_id')
        ->select('codigo', 'producto.id AS productoID')
        ->where('os.id', $request->idOrden)->get();

       foreach($productos as $p){
            $t[$p->productoID] = $p->codigo;
        }
        
        return response()->json($t);
    }
    
}

public function getCliente(Request $request)
 {
   
    if($request->ajax()){

        $clientes = ordenDS::join('cliente','cliente.id','=','os.cliente_id')
        ->select('RFC', 'cliente.id AS clienteID')
        ->where('os.id', $request->idOS)->get();

       foreach($clientes as $o){
            $t[$o->clienteID] = $o->RFC;
        }
        
        return response()->json($t);
    }
    
}
```

> Video tutorial con el cual me guie

https://youtu.be/kFtLMvu2geE